# Python Understanding Why Lines are Skipped

Tags: python, file, input, io, newline

I'm trying to read line by line from an input file in Python as shown below.

```
in1 = open("input.txt", "r")

for i in in1:
  a1 = in1.readline()
  print(a1)

in1.close()
```

The input file contains numbers as shown below:

```
13245
546464
46516
684186
```

For some reason it only prints every other line with newlines in between but I don't see why.

```
546464

684186
```

I would expect a1 to intially store "13245\n" then "546464\n" on the next iteration and so on until "684186\n".  If I use readlines() instead of readline() it skips the initial number while storing the remaining ones with "\n" in a list.

```
['546464\n', '46516\n', '684186']
```

Why does it do so? Does it have to do with the newline "\n" character being read? I know there's other ways of reading files line by line but I want to understand why this doesn't work as expected when it does in other languages (C++, Java) using a similar structure. It's not about finding the code to do so but to understand why this code behaves the way it does.

Comment: it's because you are calling `readline()` while looping over the file object. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you iterate over your file twice - in your `for` loop and using `readline`. So you will print every second line in your file.

You can use only the `for` loop:

```
in1 = open("input.txt", "r")
for a1 in in1:
  print(a1)
in1.close()
```

or using `readlines()` to read all lines as a list and iterate over them:

```
in1 = open("input.txt", "r")
for a1 in in1.readlines():
  print(a1)
in1.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
in1 = open("input.txt", "r")

for i in in1:
  print(i)

in1.close()
```

The for loop already does a readline, hence you do it twice per step.